# Angular2 Directive that Projects Copies of a Collection of <tr>

Tags: typescript, angular

With this data and html code, how can I build a component that creates the result html? The `<head>` and `<tbody>` sections are projected and I know how to project multiple elements, but I'm not sure how to repeat the projected `<tr>` in the body. In angular1 it's a simple matter of selectively compiling the elements and binding them. Even manually keeping track of the copies was pretty simple (a simplified clone of `ngRepeat`). I have this created as a working angular1 directive, but I'm lost how to translate it to angular2. In angular1, because of how I selectively compile parts of the table, you can put directives on the `<thead>` and children, as well as the `<tbody>`. Anything placed on any of `<tbody>`'s children will get repeated and compiled for each element of the passed in array.

JSON

```
[
  {name: "bob", number: "555-1234"},
  {name: "fred", number: "555-1235"},
  {name: "joe", number: "555-1236"}
]
```

HTML

```
<table sortable="person in people">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{person.name}}</td>
      <td>{{person.number}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Result

```
<table sortable="person in people">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Number</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>bob</td>
      <td>555-1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fred</td>
      <td>555-1235</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>joe</td>
      <td>555-1236</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `sortable` attribute can either be `[sortable]` or `*sortable`.

Answer (score 0):

You would use *ngFor
Here is the pseudo-code:

```
<table>
<thead>..stuff...</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="#dataItem in sourceDataList".
<td> ${dataItem.name}  </td>
<td> ${dataItem.number} </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The component adds other special behaviors besides a simple row repeater, and the point of this component is to avoid having to write *ngFor each time we a table. It was fairly easy to accomplish this in Angular 1.x.